# Convert String from Element to working HTML code with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having a checkbox which is generated dinamically. The Checkbox text contains a string with some html code inside of it. The text comes directly from the database and doesn't display it as html, but just as a string. Is it possible to convert the string to html, so it get displayed correctly? The checkbox:

```
  <label for="id_122_gen">"I hereby consent to the processing of my above-mentioned data according 
  to the <a href="/declarationofconsent.pdf" target="_blank">declaration of consent." </label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="id_122_gen" >
```

I tried to get the containing text with $.text() method, what worked so far.

```
  $mystring = $("#id_122_gen").text();
```

After that I've tried to use jQuery method $.parseHTML() and save the result again.

```
  $myhtml = $.parseHTML( $mystring );
```

Apparantly it is saved as an array, because when I try to save the result again with the $.text() method, it displays:

[object Text],/declarationofconsent.pdf,[object Text]

It's just this. No clickable link and the checkbox disappeared aswell. I'm a bit confused now what to do and don't know how I can display the correct content with a clickable link.

Comment: You can use `.html(htmlString)` to add an html string to an element.

Comment: You'd have to set the text as the innerHTML of the label, but I'm not sure how to do that with jquery (haven't used it in years).
That said, the HTML in your <label> tag is invalid.  The anchor tag is never closed.  Also, setting innerHTML like that can be risky if there's any chance that text can be controlled by a user.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem - you're trying to get it after it's already been converted to a string - why not **display it initially** as HTML?  "*The text comes directly from the database and doesn't display it as html, but just as a string*" - "doesn't display it as html" - fix this problem,

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how the html of your page is generated. Your label either has  has it's inner html escaped or not.

**This is important;** inspect view may guide you wrong with escaped HTML and show as proper HTML, so make sure to check the page source.
Most likely your data is HTML escaped and that's why you can't see the link on initial render.

If you see **&lt;** and **&gt;** inside the label's source it's HTML escaped.

If it's escaped and you just want to convert it to proper HTML and set it to the label, use this:

```
$("label[for='id_122_gen']").html( $("label[for='id_122_gen']").text() );
```

Basically this unescapes the label's value. It reads the innerHTML as text and thus changes the escaped characters to real ones, and when you set it back as it's html value and the innerHTML becomes unescaped.

If you just want to get the link, read on.

---

If the value inside the label is HTML escaped then you'll have to use .text() to read that value. If it contains unescaped HTML then you'll have to use .html().

Afterwards the flow is the same, you parse the html first.
Since there is text and a link, the parsed html will return as an array with multiple elements. If you just want to get the link you have to search in the array.
You can check out the code below.

```
$mystring = $("label[for='id_122_gen']").text(); //Use .html() for unescaped
$myhtml = $.parseHTML( $mystring ); 
var mylink = null;
var e;
while (e = $myhtml.pop())
{
  if(e.tagName == "A"){
    mylink = e;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(mylink);
```